# Get a Twig file by relative path then include it in base.html.twig in app folder

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.3, symfony-3.3

This is my `iframe` code in my base template:

```
<iframe id="main" src="{{ app.request.getBaseURL() }}/include/main.html.twig"></iframe>
```

In my app folder I have another folder named `include/` that has a twig file named `main.html.twig`.

I want to include the `main.html.twig` file in `src` like this:

```
<iframe id="main" src="/include/main.html.twig"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't  work this way . You  cannot/shouldn't  directly link to twig files.
That is  what  you need to do :

- Create new action in controller , that  will render that main.html.twig, and name it. (read about routing and @Route annotation)
- in iframe you need to use  `src="{{ path('route_name_to created action') }}"`